# Properties file seems to be producing a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception

I'm attempting to alter the base URL via a value stored in a properties file, making the process of altering environments more simple however when triggering my tests the value of the URL seems to contain null, instead of the type of environment.

```
public class Global_Vars {
    private static String testEnvironment;

        static {
            try{
                Properties props = new Properties();
                File file = new File(Global_Vars.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
                FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
                props.load(fileInput);

                // process properties content
                testEnvironment = props.getProperty("testEnvironment");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }
    }

    //GLOBAL URL's
    public static String HOMEPAGE_URL = "https://" + testEnvironment + ".deltaway.co.uk/";
```

My properties file contains the following value:

```
testEnvironment=test3
```

Also the location of the properties directory (Global_Vars.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY) is correct, any ideas?

Comment: Try doing e.printStackTrace() instead of ex.getMessage(); for a start, this will give you for details about the problem

Comment: Perhaps you are not aware that static variables are initialized in the order they appear in the class definition?

Comment: Print out `props` after you have loaded them to see if that worked. Also print the exception that you may have gotten. `ex.getMessage()` does nothing, use `e.printStacktrace()`

Comment: Also, no need to write your own code for this. Use a configuration library (like https://github.com/lightbend/config )

Comment: Thanks looks like using printStackTrace() did the trick, looks like the use is with the properties file directory, when replacing the existing value with the full path of the file, it seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the properties file could not be found. You can trace it by printing the exception (instead of  ex.getMessage() --> throw the exception or write it to log/console).

Pay attention to the location of the properties file. The recommended location for resources files is: src/main/resources

The following code (based on your code) will solve the problem:

```
    package main;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class PopertiesFileSeemsToBeProducingANullPointerException {

        private static String testEnvironment;
        private static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "src/main/resources/envs.properties";

        //GLOBAL URL's
        public static String HOMEPAGE_URL = "https://" + testEnvironment + ".deltaway.co.uk/";

        static {
            try{
                Properties props = new Properties();
                File file = new File(PopertiesFileSeemsToBeProducingANullPointerException.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
                FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
                props.load(fileInput);

                // process properties content
                testEnvironment = props.getProperty("testEnvironment");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(testEnvironment);

        }

    }
```

But I won't recommend using this code since it has some issues:

1. resource leakage - input stream was not closed properly.
2. static code - hard to test & hard to maintain
3. NO constants

A better implementation will be to add an interface Iconfig
And Config class that implements the interface

I suggest solving the problem in the following way:

The IConfig interface:

```
public interface IConfig {
    public void init();
}
```

The Config class:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import lombok.Data;

    @Data
    public class Config implements IConfig{
        private final  String PROPERTIES_FILE = "envs.properties";
        private final  String ENVIRONMENT = "testEnvironment";  
        private String env;

        public void init(){
            try(InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE)){
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.load(is);
                env = props.getProperty(ENVIRONMENT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read properties file due to IO issues");
            }
        }
    }
```

Load the configuration in your driver:

```
    @Autowired
    IConfig config;

    private void loadConfig() {
        config.init();
    }
```

You can print the desired env:

```
System.out.println(config.getEnv());
```